# How to hook into tileload event with React-Leaflet v3

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I'm looking for a way to hook into the leaflet Events `tileload` or `tileloadstart` with react-leaflet (v3.1.0). However, they are not available in useMapEvents() or accessible in the TileLayer component.

Any idea where I could hook into them? I'm trying to reload markers when the map changes (movestart, moveend, etc. are to imprecise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `eventHandlers` prop on `TileLayer` component:

```
<MapContainer center={props.position} zoom={13}>
    <TileLayer
        eventHandlers={{ tileload: () => console.log('tile loaded') }}
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    />
</MapContainer>
```